# Different ways to declare VB variables?

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to VB.NET programming.  What I'm confused about is the different ways one can declare a variable.  Would someone please explain the difference between the two declarations below?

```
Dim sqlcommand As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(sql, db)
```

And:

```
Dim anotherSqlcommand As New MySqlDataAdapter(sql, db)
```

Comment: For the record, those aren't "declarations," they're *definitions.*  Your *declaration* is 'Dim sqlCommand As MySqlDataAdapter'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference.

Sometimes you want to use the first method though if you want to take advantage of interfaces...

```
Dim myList As IList(Of Something) = New List(Of Something)
```

Instead of being restricted to List(Of Something)

```
Dim myList As New List(Of Something)
```

Comment: Also, sometimes you want to declare a variable without creating an instance of it right away.

Comment: So using interfaces would be the only reason for using the first example?  If so, if you are not using any interfaces, one should always use the second example?

Comment: Really, it doesn't change anything, but the second way is nicer, there is less duplication.

Comment: @mudface, you can do the same this with descendant classes, IE, Dim myAnimal As Animal = New Dog("Spot")

Answer (score 0):

There's actually no difference between those two but if you need to get an object from another function you have to create it this way:

Dim sqlcommand As MySqlDataAdapter = CreateSqlDataAdapter(sql, db)

and you can't put new in there.